# Making filefield link through foreign key object

Tags: python, django, web

How can I create a link to the particular file?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ....

class Presentation(models.Model):
    pres_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='presentation', null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class Participant(models.Model):
    conference = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name = 'members', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) #Post class
    presentation = models.ForeignKey(Presentation, related_name = 'pres', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'plan/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

post_detail.html

```
{% for part in post.members.all %}
      <a href="{{presentation.upload.url}}">{{part.presentation}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

part.presentation returns only Presentation description. But, I also need a file link. How can I solve this problem?

(Structure: there is a post with information about conference participants, presentations, etc. Presentation descriprion link should open a pdf file in browser)

EDIT1: Thanks. That works, but now I have a wrong media direction.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = 'plan/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

So when I upload files through admin panel, files are stored in "media/presentation" (as it written in Presentation model). But request is sent to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/plan/1/plan/media/presentation/". What can I change or add to solve this?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. `part.presentation` returns the full Presentation object, not just the description; `part.presentation.upload.url` would work fine.

Comment: The way your models are set up, you have a one-to-many relationship (ForeignKey) between Participant and Presentation.. so you can have more than one Presentation.  If that's not what you want, use a OneToOne field.  If it is, then you need to use a nested for loop to iterate over all the Presentations.

Comment: ForeignKey is what I really need) Creation of a new post with all relevant information in admin panel is provided with convenient forms to add everything i need. Though it can be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Solved. Just changed

```
MEDIA_URL = 'plan/media/'
```

to

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```